# Unable to Install Jenkins on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, jenkins

Unable to Install Jenkins on Ubuntu 16.04. I have installed Ubuntu on my computers and trying to configure Jenkins on it however it gives SSL error

Commands which fails

```
apt-get install jenkins
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libevent-core-2.0-5 libllvm4.0 snapd-login-service
Use 'apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  daemon
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  daemon jenkins
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 7 not upgraded.
Need to get 71.6 MB/71.7 MB of archives.
After this operation, 74.6 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Err:1 https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable binary/ jenkins 2.289.3             
  server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none
E: Failed to fetch https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable/binary/jenkins_2.289.3_all.deb  server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
root
```

Answer (score 3):

try run

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

With that you are going to update the openssl packages to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

Well  Just Try

```
sudo apt-get clean
```

if you have installed the repositories, Re-install Jenkins after

```
sudo apt-get update
```

then, install

```
sudo apt-get install Jenkins
```